# Amplifying 5 V, 2 MHz signal to 40 V

Tags: voltage, amplifier

What is the simplest, cheapest way to amplify a 5V signal in the 2 MHz range to around 40V? I need this in order to power a piezoelectric element.

Comment: How much power / current?  Sinusoidal or other waveform?

Comment: You may need an intermediate stage due to GBW limits, but a high voltage op-amp (such as the [LTC6090](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC6090)) ought to suffice. I'm assuming the piezo doesn't require huge currents.

Comment: A piezoelectric element can have a very large capacitance and so require significant power to drive.  You need to understand what those requirements are. Do you have a data sheet for the element?

Answer (score 1):

Think about this: Gate Driver into PI network

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4B1Cb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You can actually replace R1 with an inductor to get a little more efficiency too. This might be necessary because the amplification required (8) is quite high but +1 for using the same idea as a colpitts oscillator.

Comment: I've used this at 100KHz, with GateDrivers to produce 30 volt resonant swings.